# Make 2 arrays ($B and $C) using $A elements that [ (sum of $B elements) - (sum of $C elements) ] equals minimum number (0 if possible)?

Tags: php, arrays, element

For example, we have array `$A` with 11 elements (no matter if is odd number, then it can be 5 elements in `$B` and 6 elements in `$C`, or 8 elements in `$C` and 3 elements in `$C`). The result must satisfy rules from the title

```
$A = array(1, 2, 5, 7, 12, 11, 9, 13, 10, 3, 2)

$B = array(....)

$C = array(....)
```

that satisfy (sum of `$B` elements) - (sum of `$C` elements) = minimum number (0 if possible)

Comment: What PHP code can you assemble and edit into the post that does any small part of the task. It's hard for us to know what you don't know without a minimal stab at solving the problem by you...

Comment: So, for your example, I can take `$B = array(1)` and `$C = array(2, 5, 7, 12, 11, 9, 13, 10, 3, 2)` ? Because if yes, (sum of $B) - (sum of $C) = 1 - 74 = -73, which is smaller than zero.

Comment: See [help], point #3: _Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the numbers in $A, then start moving them into $B and $C from the front or end of $A as needed, keeping them sorted as well. When done, you can do binary search and shift items back and forth as needed to balance. I'll add a code example if you'd like